# How to find the roots of the second derivative of $ f(x)=x^2(x − 3)^3$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, roots

I am horrid at factoring and I have to find the inflection points of $ f(x)=x^2(x − 3)^3$. So I to find the inflection points I need to set $f'$ equal to $0$ So I have   $f'(x)=2x(x-3)^3+x^2\cdot3(x-3)^2$ and after some simplifying I ended with $5x^4-36x^3+81x^2-54x$ But I do not know go to go from there. I know one zero is $\frac{6}{5}$ but I do not know how to reach that. A step by step factorization would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Where the function is increasing and decreasing. Inflection points are later.

Comment: Inflection points are where the *concavity* changes. So we are interested in the behaviour of $f''$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas sorry, I meant where the function is increasing and decreasing for the part of the question I am working on.

Comment: Simplify **just enough**. The common factor $(x-3)^2$ in your calculation is precious, bring it to the front. Expanding as you hid that nice $(x-3)^2$ from view.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes, I see that now. It's so simple now. Thanks!

Comment: And in fact, since the function $f$ itself is already nicely factored, you can surmise that $f$ will behave locally like a parabola near $x=0$ and like a cubic near $x=3$, so we expect $f'$ to have roots at $0$ and $3$ (and another one somewhere between those).

Comment: Great observation, thanks @Théophile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2x(x-3)^3 + 3x^2(x-3)^2 = x(x-3)^2[2(x-3)+3x] = x(x-3)^2(5x-6)$